# Twig template extend ignored

Tags: php, symfony, twig, extend

I have 2 Entities: Clinic, Vet, for which I created CRUD templates with app/console generate:doctrine:crud

I first created the Clinic entity and created my "admin template" in AgriHealth/AhpBundle/Resources/views/admin.html.twig and then extend this in

```
AgriHealth/AhpBundle/Resources/views/Clinic/index.html.twig:
{% extends 'AgriHealthAhpBundle::admin.html.twig' %}
```

This worked.

Then I created Entity Vet and ran the crud generator. Again I'm extending:

```
AgriHealth/AhpBundle/Resources/views/Vet/index.html.twig:
{% extends 'AgriHealthAhpBundle::admin.html.twig' %}
```

But this seems to be ignored, as the layout from my admin template doesn't come through. I have tried:

- app/console cache:clear
- renaming admin.html.twig: causes an error in both views as expected

I must be missing something? Any ideas?

Twig code below:

src/AgriHealth/AhpBundle/Resources/views/admin.html.twig

```
    {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {{ parent() }}

        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/agrihealthahp/css/admin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/agrihealthsecurity/css/admin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endblock %}
    {% block body -%}
    <div class="row" id="header">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <h1><a href=""><img src="/bundles/agrihealthahp/images/agrihealth-logo.png" />
            <span>Animal Health Planner</span></a></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="menu">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="content">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            {% block admin %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="black_footer">
        <div class="small-12 medium-5 columns footer-black-1">
            <div class="moduletable">


                <div class="custom">
                    <p><a href="http://www.agrihealth.co.nz">www.agrihealth.co.nz</a></p></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-7 columns ">
            <div class="left footer-black-2">
                <div class="moduletable">


                    <div class="custom">
                        <p>0800 821 421</p></div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="right footer-black-3">
                <div class="moduletable">


                    <div class="custom">
                        <p><sup></sup><sup><img style="line-height: 1.1;" src="/bundles/agrihealthahp/images/agrihealth_white.png" alt="agrihealth white"></sup></p></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

src/AgriHealth/AhpBundle/Resources/views/Clinic/index.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'AgriHealthAhpBundle::admin.html.twig' %}

{% block admin -%}
<h1>Clinics</h1>


<ul class="actions">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('clinic_new') }}">
            Add Clinic
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>


<table class="records_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Fax</th>
            <th>After Hours</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ path('clinic_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.name }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ entity.phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.fax }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.afterhours }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.email }}</td>
            <td>
            <ul class="actions">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('clinic_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">edit</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>


{% endblock %}
```

src/AgriHealth/AhpBundle/Resources/views/Vet/index.html.twig:

```
    {% extends 'AgriHealthAhpBundle::admin.html.twig' %}
    {% block body -%}
        <h1>Vets</h1>

        <ul class="actions">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('vet_new') }}">
                    Add Vet
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <table class="records_list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                    <th>Clinic</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for entity in entities %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{ path('vet_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.firstname }} {{ entity.lastname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ entity.mobile }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ path('clinic_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.clinic }}</a></td>
                    <td>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ path('vet_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">edit</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>


        {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You could be overriding a block in your `MyBundleAppBundle:Vet:index.html.twig`, then again you may not but without seeing a bit more of the templates it's hard to guess. Best bet would be to stick some of your template data up and see where that goes.

Comment: @Qoop Sorry for the delay, please see twog code inserted

Comment: You've put the code for the `AgriHealth/AhpBundle/Resources/views/admin.html.twig` page up twice, what the code for `AgriHealth/AhpBundle/Resources/views/Clinic/index.html.twig`?

Comment: Please see code. Marcel found the issue though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the source of the page for the stylesheets included in admin.html.twig.

If they are there, the problem is that you are overriding your body block.

Change

src/AgriHealth/AhpBundle/Resources/views/Vet/index.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'AgriHealthAhpBundle::admin.html.twig' %}
    {% block body -%}
```

to

```
{% extends 'AgriHealthAhpBundle::admin.html.twig' %}
    {% block admin -%}
```

If your stylesheets are not in the page there must be another problem .